Engineering student doing an eco/fin project on ESG. Need additional resources
I am trying to get a fin/eco project and my prof has asked me to read a paper on ESG titled, "ESG performance and business risk—Empirical evidence from China's listed companies." I am struggling to understand the maths in the paper as it doesnt go in much detail explaining the variables. Could you suggest additional resources on ESG ratings and regression models which could help me out?

There doesn't seem to be a lot of complicated math in that paper. Perhaps you difficulty is in interpreting regression results?

@HerrK. yes, could you recommend a few resources where i can learn about it? Also struggling with brownian motion in this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1544612324009115

You need to learn statistics. There's a variety of resources out there. Any standard undergraduate textbook would do. Or find an online resource. I personally like learning it along with a coding language so I've usually recommended https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/ but up to you how far you want to go with this. ESG ratings aside, stats is required here.

@schizoproletariat In addition to Brennan's recommendation, Wooldridge or Stock and Watson are both widely used. Also, please avoid asking new questions in the comment. Feel free to post a new question on Brownian motion though.

@HerrK. could you recommend a lecture series on econometrics? Kinda have deadline to meet. I will be able to go through a lecture series quicker lol. Thanks for all the help btw
